# How to show the camera input in a website using HTML

Tags: html, ios, safari, embed

Ive decided to create a website like TokBox. But I ran into a problem wheren. When I’m using WebRTC, I don’t get the output of the camera, can someone help me? Plus if you need any more information, I’m using Safari and its allowed me to use the camera, but i just cant see the output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="stuff, to, help, search, engines, not" name="keywords">
<meta content="What this page is about." name="description">
<meta content="Display Webcam Stream" name="title">
<title>Display Webcam Stream</title>

<style>
#container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    border: 10px #333 solid;
}
#videoElement {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    background-color: #666;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">

    </video>
</div>
<script>
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
}

function handleVideo(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}
```

Oh and here, I don’t know what to put here for the errors.

```
function videoError(e) {
    // do something
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could start by adding a console.log for the error.

Safari is a bit picky about autoplaying videos, [this sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/) adds a playsinline attribute. You'll also want to use srcObject instead of URL.createObjectURL and promises with the modern version of the API.